# Does rails 3 give options to add filter inside model like validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-models

Example Case- How add filter to strip all html tags(this code not works, just psedocode for want i need to get):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  #psedocode:
  **filters:name,:strip_tags=>true**
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ActiveRecord has a bunch of [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) that you can tap into such as before_save, before_validation, etc. You can do something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :strip_tags

  private

  def strip_tags
    self.name = name.gsub(TAGS, '')
  end
end
```

More information in the [Rails guide on ActiveRecord callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview)

Comment: How you actually filter the name is up to you. If you have specific questions about filtering content, I would open a different question since you'll get better answers that way.

Comment: (dry code problem)How can strip_tags be defined in one place for all models?

Comment: Put it in a module and include it in the models you want it in.